# upload to s3 bucket folder with laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am currently using this packages for amazon file uploads and it works, the only problem is i don't know how to specify a folder in my chosen bucket.

```
Package Used - "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
```

This is how i currently upload to the bucket

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image = $request->file('image');
$t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
$imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imageName);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a path and use in put method instead of `$imageName` to store in that particular path of bucket. It'll create the folder itself according to path.

For e.g. if you set the path as `$path = "folder_1/folder_2/file.pdf"`, s3 driver will store file.pdf in folder_2 which is inside folder_1.

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image = $request->file('image');

//image stored in folder name image_folder
$path = "image_folder/".$imageName;

$t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, file_get_contents($image));
```